# On react-leaflet moving a few markers by useRef array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I'm trying to change the position of a few markers on a `react-leaflet` map according to the position of a draggable marker.
This should be while the draggable marker is dragged, changing it on the `state` will be too slow, so I chose to do it with `useRef` to an array of refs.
Problem is that `r.leafletElement.setLatLng([lat, lng])` line crushes because `leafletElement` is `undefined`.
(On other attempts i used only one marker instead of an array and `useRef` was working correctly.)
Your help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

https://codepen.io/erangeva/pen/XWdyZzw

```
const { Map: LeafletMap, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, CircleMarker } = ReactLeaflet

const Simple = ({ nums }) => {
    const refs = React.useRef([]);
    if (refs.current.length !== nums.length) {
        refs.current = nums.map((_, i) => refs.current[i] || React.createRef());
    }
    return (
        <LeafletMap center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]} draggable={true}
                ondrag={(e) => {
                    refs.current.map((r, i) => {
                        const lat = e.target.getLatLng().lat;
                        const lng = e.target.getLatLng().lng + 0.01 * i;
                        r.leafletElement.setLatLng([lat, lng]);
                    })
                }}
            >
            </Marker>
            {
                nums.map(i =>
                    <Marker position={[51.505, -0.08 + 0.01 * i]}
                        ref={refs.current[i]}
                    >
                    </Marker>)
            }
        </LeafletMap>
    );

}


ReactDOM.render(<Simple nums={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the way how `refs` is initialized, it has the the following structure:

```
{
   current: [
       {current: Marker},
       ... 
   ]
}
```

meaning underlying marker object needs to be addressed like this:

```
r.current.leafletElement.setLatLng([lat, lng]);
```

And thats the reason why the provided error occurs in the first place.

---

Another option to manipulate marker list without resorting to `Refs` is demonstrated below:

```
const MyMarkerList = ({ startPos }) => {

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState(calcPositions(startPos,4));
  
  function handleDrag(e) {
    const latLng = e.target.getLatLng();
    setPositions(calcPositions([latLng.lat, latLng.lng],4));
  }


  return (
    <>
    <Marker
        position={startPos}
        draggable={true}
        ondrag={(e) => {
          handleDrag(e);
        }}
      ></Marker>
      {positions.map((pos, i) => (
        <Marker key={i} position={pos}></Marker>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

where

```
function calcPositions(startPos,numOfPos){
  return [...Array(numOfPos)].map((v,i) => {
    return [startPos[0], startPos[1] + 0.01 * (i + 1)];
  });
}
```

Usage

```
<Map center={startPos} zoom={13}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <MyMarkerList startPos={startPos} />
  </Map>
```

Comment: Thank you! adding `current` on `r.current.leafletElement.setLatLng([lat, lng]);` solved the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by storing only the **marker** **positions** instead of the **marker DOM references** which are complicated and expensive objects to store in memory.

Here initialise the position of the draggable markers and the markers to be moved. The first one will be an array and the latter an array of arrays containing the positions of the markers to be moved:

```
const [marker, setMarker] = useState([51.505, -0.09]);

const initialMarkersState = nums.map((n) => [51.505, -0.08 + 0.01 * n]);

const [markers, setMarkers] = useState(initialMarkersState);
```

On the drag event listener change the position of the draggable marker and change also the position of the all the other markers using setMarker and setMarkers setState methods.

```
const handleMarkerDrag = (e) => {
    setMarker(e.latlng);
    const lat = e.target.getLatLng().lat;
    const lng = e.target.getLatLng().lng + 0.01;
    setMarkers((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      nums.forEach((n) => {
        newState[n] = [lat, lng + 0.01 * n];
      });
      return newState;
    });
  };
```

Finally render the markers by looping over the markers array.

```
{markers.map((position, i) => (
    <Marker position={position} key={i} icon={icon}></Marker>
))}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-change-the-position-of-markers-according-to-the-position-of-a-draggable-one-in-react-leaflet-rrvwj?file=/src/App.js:1149-1256)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am trying to avoid re-rendering as it is slower than just moving the markers, as on vanilla leaflet.

Comment: I believe what you are doing is slower and crushes the browser even with 5 markers rendered. In the example I provided, even if you place 100 markers it works smoothly. Only if you place 1000 markers the performance will start being slow but this is normal as the markers are really expensive to render a lot of them on the DOM and other approaches should be followed like using circle markers on a canvas, etc.

Comment: I need refs for each marker for other abilities of `leaflet` that `react-leaflet` has not implemented yet, outside the scope of the question. Thanks a lot for your answer.